# custom css styles from (within - inside) wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet, dashboard

I am looking to edit the css styles from inside the Dashboard inside of wordpress ***and NOT have to edit the php files if possible.***

I know it is possible to edit at least some of the properties so my hope is I can edit all of them right within the dashboard.

**MORE SPECIFICALLY** 
How can I change the css states of links and submenus of a custom class? For example the a:active, a:hover, a:link etc... and ALL OF THE SUB-MENUS to custom css as well?

I have included these pictures to show you what I am trying to do and the present results.

**MY CUSTOM MENU INSIDE OF WORDPRESS**

[image]

**CUSTOM CSS INSIDE OF WORDPRESS**
[image]

**THE RESULTS**

[image]

Comment: I think if you set an !important after it, then it might work. such as **color:#1c61ff !important;**

Comment: may be useful to inspect particular element to investigate where it inherits `color:` style from? Sometime ago I watched video of landing-page creation within WP. That cool man just radically totally used `!important` attribute to customize styles )))

Comment: I think the most soft method is to take courage and edit header.php to place link to custom.css below of link to default WP style.css

Comment: so try to inspect an element with debug console (Shift+Ctrl+I in chrome). may be an item has inline style attribute that has higher priority than styles from css-file

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking the time to give a little more details in gratitude for all the help I got on stackoverflow over the years, also giving a little more info for the newbies out there. We are all learning.

Here is what worked in pictures

1. I used Firefox and used "INSPECT ELEMENT". While on the page I did a LEFT CLICK and from drop down I chose INSPECT ELEMENT.

[image]

1. Then I clicked on the PICK AN ELEMENT icon, as seen in the picture and then I hovered over the element I wanted to edit, in this case a button in the menu. This gave me the class I needed to edit.
2. I went into my DASHBOARD in WordPress and made this change to the code. Finally I got the results I was looking for, which I also included in the same picture as well.

[image]

Although I have not figured out how to edit the sub-menus yet I believe I am on the right track and will figure it out.

**HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE. :)**